# Will Android ListView load faster than Customized View?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I need to display a complicated list in my app. On each row there will be a checkbox and some TextView.

I know this could be done via ListView/Adapter, but I was worried it requires too much tweaking to make it fits my specific requirement, so I just created my own customized MyListView inheriting LinearLayout. On initiating, it adds MyListViewItem (inherited from RelativeLayout) dynamically.

The customized view functions fine. However, I notice that the rendering speed of MyListView is a little too slow, so I wondered will it be faster if I use ListView/Adapter instead?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The benefit of using ListView rather than a great big LinearLayout is that the OS can do a better job of optimizing when views are inflated, and the recycling of views, based on what is actually visible to the user. It also makes it easier to perform common actions such as scrolling to a particular row.

Comment: Thanks. I tested it and it's indeed much faster.

Answer (score 1):

ListView recycles its items. So, yes, it will work much more efficiently in case of a large number of list items. And as a result you'll obtain a less complicated view hierarchy.